# Accessing on-premise Dynamics v8 via OData using RestSharp/System.Net.Http

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, ntlm-authentication, www-authenticate

I'm trying to access data from our on-premise Dynamics (v8) via OData WebService using RestSharp / System.Net.Http but in this case, I'm kind of stuck. I fiddled around a couple of days now and the problem seems to be somewhere around the authentication but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The URL I'm sending a GET-Request to is `https://host.fqdn/systemenv01/api/data/v8.2/$metadata` using a valid Windows domain user account that is able to log on to the dynamics normally. When I try this in Firefox or the latest version of Postman (v7.36) using NTLM-Auth I get a proper metadata XML as the result.

But when I try the same using RestSharp or simply System.Net.Http I only get an HTTP401-Unauthorized as a response. What I tried to do is setting the user credentials as NetworkCredentials like

```
var client = new RestClient(Url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
client.FollowRedirects = true;
client.Timeout = -1;
client.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Password);
```

but this doesn't seem to make any difference at all. Interestingly the response contains a header with the name "WWW-Authenticate" and the value "Negotiate some.encrypted.string" but I don't know what I should use this for. Would be great if someone could help me get this solved!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: any specific reason why you are not using the official SDK?

Comment: I would be fine using some SDK or Nuget package as long as it represents a standard OData implementation. The "bigger goal" I'm trying to achieve is to have a generic OData-connector for our software solution. The reason why sticking to the standard is important is, because it should connect to Dynamics Online and on-premise systems as well as non-Microsoft OData-Services such like Software AG's Mediator or SAP Netweaver.

Comment: I tried doing the request in Edge (Chromium) and Google Chrome and it seems like Firefox is the only browser that actually can authenticate correctly. I searched the web and came across this bug-report which might be relevant [https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8038](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8038)

Comment: Tiny update on this: Like mentioned in this article [https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221693](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221693) WWW-Authenticate=Negotiate header indicates, that I should use Kerberos as Auth-mechanism. I implemented this in a prototype application using Kerberos.Net Nuget-Package but applying a valid Kerberos-Ticket to the request doesn't lead to success as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something very interesting:

The authentication works perfectly when I replace the domain name of the Dynamics system with its IP address.

I do not know this for sure but this domain is below the TLD `.dev` which has HSTS activated by default.

I even tried connecting using another FQDN from another TLD (which was `.net`) and this worked perfectly as well.

Therefore I conclude the issue is originated in the configuration and handling of HSTS.