# How to add credentials to ODATA Microsoft dynamics web service, on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: web-services, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, odata, dynamics-business-central

The Microsoft dynamic web service link when used on a browser prompts the Credentials as shown in the image below
[image]

The issue is how to pass this credential to Visual studio in order to avoid the Unauthorized response

[image]

I have tried:

```
Authorisation:Basic
username: valid username
password: valid password
```

on the Custom Headers textbox, having ticked include custom http headers

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65200911/1911064), you can supply the user credentials as follows:

```
var client = new RestClient(Url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
client.FollowRedirects = true;
client.Timeout = -1;
client.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Password);
```

You already replaced the domain name of the Dynamics system with its IP address. Make sure that the service is actually active. Are there any access restrictions in place which prevent the user from calling this service? Check the event log entries on the server side.

Test the connection/credentials with [postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/).
Such a test can rule-out problems outside your code.
If [postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) is able to perform a sucessful call, your code is the culprit.

`Campany` in the service URL is not spelled correctly?

Comment: Hello @Axel, the issue am experiencing is not the access with Postman but using the ODATA package.